# Caching, when using htaccess url rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, caching, browser-cache

If I use this rewrite rule to rename any javascript file that looks like `js.20140820.js` to `js.js`

```
RewriteRule ^(js|css)\.(.+)\.(js|css)$ $1.$3 [L]
// needs work
```

And the user already has the file js.js in cache, **will that file be loaded from cache in this case?**

His/her browser did not request that file (js.js), so I imagine it might be handled differently

Comment: Browser will look at its cache while it's the same number in filename. Once you update it, browser will load new file (and not its cache). You have another possibility like using `filemtime` in PHP and prefixing it this way: `js.js?XXXXXXX` where `XXXXXXX` is the result of `filemtime('js.js')`

Comment: @JustinIurman Yes, I'm using query on files right now, but want to upgrade as it's far from always reliable (proxyservers etc.) ;) Didn't quite understand your first line. The browser will or will NOT use js.js from cache if that is not the directly requested file?

Comment: Like i told you in my previous comment, it's not about `js.js` file since your browser is searching for `js.XXXXXX.js` (it's the server itself that serves the file in background). So browsers will not load file from cache the first time they try it. For example, you made an update and change its name: `js.123456789.js`. The browser does not have that file in cache so it loads it. But after, and till you update again, it will load from cache. Browser never knows about real `js.js` file

Comment: Oh ok. Just wanted to be sure what you meant ;) That is good news, and makes it somewhat easy to have version number in filename. Do you know any site/article that describes it?

Comment: Yep. There are 2 well known way of doing: yours (via htaccess) or `filemtime` via PHP. Both are working the way you want. I don't have a link right now but you can find a lot with a search

Comment: I think maybe I'm gonna combine them. But only using filemtime locally, as it's not good for performance (if many files). And/or perhaps check ONE file for changes, and use that info as filename on all the css/js files. Something like that, don't know yet

Comment: Post an answer :) Especially if you have a quote/link to documentation

Comment: this is not what I'm finding.  For some reason the file is not getting loaded from browser cache when I do a rewrite, even if it's actually requesting the same file each time.